# Why when I draw autocomplete polygons using a frame`s border, it doesn`t work inside the frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, polygon-creation

I try to create an Auto-complete polygon within a bigger frame (from the same layer), using frame's border. The thing is that when I try to create it outside the frame, the polygon appear but when I'm trying to do inside, it doesn't work. I tried many times and every time, outside it worked and outside,no.

[image: inside]

[image: outside]

[image: outside result]

Why is this situation ? What can I do in order to succeed making autocomplete polygons inside the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-complete Polygon fills *gaps* with new polygons.  They only work where there is no existing polygon.

[image]

Where there are existing polygons, the auto-complete polygon tool will **not** create any polygons.

This will not create a polygon as there is no gap:

[image]

No polygon created:

[image]

In fact, the tool needs to actually cross an area where there is no existing polygon in order to create a polygon there.  If I have a hole which I fully surround by my auto-complete polygon sketch, but without crossing any of the gap, no polygon will be created.

This will not auto-complete any polygon:

[image]

However this will, as it crosses the gap:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, man. It worked.